# Given a line from -i to i and a semi circle from -i to i, evaluate the integral over both and explain why they are different

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, parametrization

Let gamma 1 be a straight line from -i to i and let gamma 2 be the semi-circle of radius 1 in the right half plane from -i to i.

Evaluate

$$\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz$$

and $$\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz$$

where f(z)=complex conjugate(z)

And give a reason as to why the two answers are different.

---

**My approach:**

Let $$\gamma_1=(1-t)(-i)+it = i2t-i|t\in[0,1]$$

and

Let $$\gamma_2=e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)|\frac{3\pi}{2}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Conjugate of $\gamma_1$ $$-i2t+i$$

Conjugate of $\gamma_2$ $$\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta)$$

Integrals

$$\int_0^1-i2t+idt=0$$

$$\int_\frac{3\pi}{2}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos(\theta) - i\sin(\theta) = 2$$

Is the above work correct?

Also, would "the integrals are different because the paths/curves were parameterised differently" be a valid reason??

Comment: @Arthur"where f(z)=complex conjugate(z)" it's written above. f(x+iy)=x-iy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is on the right path, however you forgot to multiply by the derivative of the curves in the integrals. The general formula for an integral over a parameterized curve is 
$$ \int_\gamma f(t) \: dt = \int_a^b f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \: dt $$

Also i would probably chose angles $\theta \in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ for the second curve.

Also note that IF $f$ was holomorphic in a simply connected domain containing the two curves, THEN the integrals would have been the same, hence we can conclude that this is not the case (which of course could be verified directly using cauchy-riemann equations).

Comment: Thank you very much. Also, are my angles wrong?

Comment: Yes and no. Computation wise the answer is the same, however a curve should be defined on an interval and $[3\pi/2 , \pi/2]$ is not an interval.

By definition $\int_{3\pi/2}^{\pi/2} g(t) dt = - \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi /2} g(t) dt$, thus technically you are integrating along the curve in "the wrong direction" and then multiply by -1, which essentially gives the same as just integrating in the right direction.

Therefore i would say $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ is a better choice of angles, although the answer is the same.

Answer (score 2):

$f(z) = \bar{z}$ doesn't satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations so it's not holomorphic. Therefore we can't assume that integrals along different paths give the same value as Cauchy's integral theorem fails.

Comment: Is this the reason? Also, for proving that it's not holomorphic. Do we take u(x,y)=x and v(x,y)=-y and thus (u_x=1), (v_y=-1) 1=/=-1? And, is the parametrisation I did correct?

Comment: That's the reason and you're right about how to prove it. The parametrisation looks good.

Comment: thank you very much. I am taking a complex analysis (havent even heard of the subject before) class and I am feeling quite overwhelmed by all the types of integrations (cauchy, residue thm, etc). Your help is very appreciated.